# Cannot recognize java 8 lambda but the configuration is ok

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I imported a program in Intellij with Spring and Hibernate and all Java 8 stuff and I have a problem that Java 8 is not seen. The JDK is set and the imports are OK; I really don't understand why my IDE underlines this code in red. The code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Book> bookList;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String name, List<Book> bookList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Book> getBookList() {
        return bookList;
    }

    public void setBookList(List<Book> bookList) {
        this.bookList = bookList;
    }

    public Set<Book> getBooks() { // !!!!! here lines 1
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet( // 2
                this.bookList.stream(). // 3
                        collect(Collectors.toSet()));//4 are red
    }
```

And also the `import` statement:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

is red as well. When I click on on the error it says:

```
Incompatible types.Required set <packet.model.book> 
                  Found set <java.lang.Object>
```

What could be the problem on the first side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use maven, right? If yes, please check your java version defined in the `pom.xml`, If it's not defined, IDE uses default value which could be different from `1.8`.

You can use [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html) and set the jdk version to `1.8` explicitly:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please, make sure that you have also set the language level to Java 8. If you go **File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project**, you can configure both project SDK and project language level there. Make sure both are set to Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Set java 8 in project structure `ctrl+alt+s` or `File -> Project Structure`

see the following image

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]